# Algoritmo - Como pegar os dias em uma semana JS

Tags: javascript, json, algoritmo, data

Eu tenho a seguinte situação: Preciso setar os dias de cada semana dentro de um mês, criando um array de objetos JSON.

Cada posição corresponderia a uma semana, por exemplo caso houvesse 5 semanas eu teria um array de 5 posições, onde cada posição seria um objeto onde o dia da semana seria a key, e o dia do mês o valor desta key.

exemplo:

```
0: {segunda:02/05, terça: 03/05 ...}
1: {...quinta:n/n, sexta:n/n}
```

Tentei realizar isto utilizando o objeto de datas **Date** mas eu não consegui, como eu poderia criar este algoritmo?

Comment: Seu mês seria o corrente ou algum definido?

Comment: seria o mês atual @Marconi

Comment: E como deve aparecer a segunda feira caso ainda pertença ao mês anterior?

Comment: À parte da tua pergunta aqui, mas relacionado podes dar uma olhada [a este projeto](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/js-calendar) no Github, ele gera algo parecido ao que procuras.

Comment: eu acabei me equivocando no exemplo e mudando o mês, mas caso o mês não tivesse uma segunda não deveria ser setado nesta aplicação onde engloba apenas o mês vigente.

Comment: quanto ao projeto, o mesmo geraria para mim objetos para eu setar em um date picker por exemplo?

Comment: @MarcosHenrique, exato, eu fiz [esse projeto](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/js-calendar) para servir de motor a um calendário. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/La7cwne8/

Comment: @MarcosHenrique em relação à pergunta: a array começa com o dia 1 de cada mês ou com a segunda feira da primeira semana do mês?

Comment: então em relação ao array, deveria ser setado a partir do primeiro dia do mês independendo do dia da semana que começasse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como sugeri nos comentários dá uma olhada a este projeto [*js-Calendar*](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/js-calendar) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/La7cwne8/)), pois acho que faz muito do que precisas. É um gerador de datas com dias de semana, etc.

Mas respondendo à pergunta específica podes fazer assim:

```
var diasSemana = ['Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado', 'Domingo'];

function diaSemana(nr) {
    return diasSemana[nr % 7]; // dar nomes ao numero do dia de semana
}

function diasMes(ano, mes) {
    var semanas = []; // array a preencher
    var semana = {};
    var diaUm = new Date(ano, mes - 1); // dia um do mês
    var inicioSemana = diaUm.getDay() - 1; // numero do dia da semana (começando na segunda)
    var ultimoDia = new Date(ano, mes, -1).getDate(); // quantidade de dias no mês
    for (var i = 1; i <= ultimoDia; i++) {
        var dia = diaSemana(inicioSemana++); // dar nome ao dia da semana
        semana[dia] = [i, mes].join('/'); // dia do mês / mês
        if (i % 7 == 0) { // caso mude a semana
            semanas.push(semana);
            semana = {}
        } else {
            if (i == ultimoDia) semanas.push(semana); // juntar os ultimos dias
        }
    }
    return semanas;
}

var janeiro = diasMes(2016, 1);
alert(JSON.stringify(janeiro, null, 4));
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/898thd7e/1

Fiz esse código agora, testa para ver se não tem um bug escondido.

Comment: Cara fiz parcialmente o que você fez e com seu código encontrei o porque estava errando tanto.

Além disso vale salientar que tendo estas duas soluções fica ainda mais fácil de eu decidir qual utilizar para minha aplicação, utilizarei as duas, agradeço e muito o feedback.

Comment: @MarcosHenrique fico contente de ter ajudado.